# find smallest number $M$ for which the remainder of $N/M$ is equal to $3$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

given a positive integer $N$ greater than $3$, is there a smart or algorithmic way to find the smallest number $M$ for which the remainder of $N/M$ equals $3$? one obvious answer is always $N-3$, but this is rarely the smallest one.

Comment: For $N\in\{4,5,6\}$ no such $M$ exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired $M$ is the smallest divisor of $N-3$ that is greater than $3$. If you have the prime factorization of $N-3$, this is easy to find; if not, I don't know an efficient procedure. (There is of course a *simple* procedure: just test possible divisors starting with $4$.)

Comment: Wow. Didn't think of that, but you are perfectly correct. Thanks!

Comment: @user2659185: You're welcome!